# REGEXP_EXTRACT in Impala

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I am trying to figure out how to extract customer ID from string that looks loke this:

```
{"param":"success","value":"10","level":"0","error_code":"101","customer_id":"5b0e9b23e423b0d33c9f7ddfd", "purchases": "13", "last_activity_ts": "123523465"}
```

I am trying to extract customer ID from strings that contain error code 101 with following code:

```
select regexp_extract(field, '\"customer_id":"(.*)', 0) from table_name
where field rlike '"error_code":"101"'
```

But this gives me a following result:

```
"customer_id":"5b0e9b23e423b0d33c9f7ddfd", "purchases": "13", "last_activity_ts": "123523465"}
```

Expected result:

```
5b0e9b23e423b0d33c9f7ddfd
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below regex:

```
"customer_id":"(\w+)"
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/MEOGw8/39

Test:

```
{"param":"success","value":"10","level":"0","error_code":"101","customer_id":"5b0e9b23e423b0d33c9f7ddfd", "purchases": "13", "last_activity_ts": "123523465"}
```

Match:

```
Match 1
Full match  63-104  `"customer_id":"5b0e9b23e423b0d33c9f7ddfd"`
Group 1.    78-103  `5b0e9b23e423b0d33c9f7ddfd`
```

SQL Statement:

```
select regexp_extract(field, '"customer_id":"(\w+)"',1, 1) from table_name
where field rlike '"error_code":"101"'
```

Comment: Aman, thank you a lot for your answer. I am sorry, but I am still struggling to impliment this to my request. Could you please correct me?

`select regexp_extract(field_name, '"customer_id":"([\w\d]+)"', 0)`

Comment: @Nikitaisonline Please try the SQL statement I pasted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches from `"customer_id":"` until the end of the line because you use `.*` which will match any charcter zero or more times and you use `0` as the last parameter of `regexp_extract.` which refers to the entire extracted string.

To match what is between the double quotes, you could match not a double quote and capture that in a group `([^"]+)` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

[`"customer_id":"([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/ZL1lW8/1)

Or you might specify the character ranges in a character class, repeat it one or more times `([a-f0-9]+)` and capture that in a group:

[`"customer_id":"([a-f0-9]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/ZL1lW8/2)

Your value is in the first capturing group which I think you could specify using `1` as the third parameter for [regexp_extract](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html).

```
regexp_extract(field, '"customer_id":"([a-f0-9]+)"', 1)
```