# Extracting field name value from a long | separated string in Cloudera Impala using REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: impala, cloudera-cdh

I am new to REGEXP and its syntax.

I have a long string of multiple pairs in the format field_name:value separated by |
Using Impala Shell, I am trying run a SQL Select to search for a particular field_name: and then need to get whatever is in value till the next |

Tried to use this guide, but it does not give full syntax for POSIX
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html

I tried this

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN LONGSTRING IS NOT NULL
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(LONGSTRING, 'FIELD_NAME1:') = true
    THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(LONGSTRING, 'FIELD_NAME1:([^\|]+\|',1)
END AS LONGSTRING_PARSED
from Table1
```

I tried above after reading a bit on REGEX101 and reading this prior post
[REGEXP_EXTRACT in Impala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100923/regexp-extract-in-impala)

Sample long string
FIELD_NAME1:VALUE1|FIELD_NAME2:VALUE2|FIELD_NAME3:VALUE3

Sample SQL I tried

```
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN LONGSTRING IS NOT NULL
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(LONGSTRING, 'FIELD_NAME1:') = true
  THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(LONGSTRING, 'FIELD_NAME1:([^\|]+\|',1)
END AS LONGSTRING_PARSED
from Table1
```

Expecting to see
VALUE1

Actual Result
Null